# How do I prevent ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions from showing the plot?

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, jupyter, plotting

`ConfusionMatrixDisplay` docs say:

> It is recommend to use `from_estimator` or `from_predictions` to create a ConfusionMatrixDisplay.

However, I want to plot the matrix manually on some axes I configure, and when I use `from_predictions`, I can't prevent it from plotting the matrix. The result is that I get two plots shown: one from the `from_predictions` call, and one from `cmp.plot()`.

For example, this results in two plots:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(np.arange(25), np.arange(25))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
cmp.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

But this results in one:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cm = confusion_matrix(np.arange(25), np.arange(25))
cmp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=np.arange(25))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
cmp.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

**I would like to use `from_predictions`, but to have it not plot, like using the constructor.**

Notebook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lUPpp0dYfuIk1z8o7QfdUlQTt9eJ1dy4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `from_predictions` has an extra keyword argument that you can use to plot the figure on an existing `Axes` object (see also [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions), which you can use to replace the `cmp.plot(ax=ax)` call. The following should therefore do what you're looking for:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
cmp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(np.arange(25), np.arange(25), ax=ax)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, missed that somehow